# Trial function for differential equation confusion

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider $y'' + y = \cos(t)$

For a particular solution, why would the trial function be

$y = At\cos(t) + Bt\sin(t)$ instead of $y = A\cos(t) + B\sin(t)$. I'm asking where the $t$ comes from?

Comment: Note that if $y = A\cos(t) + B\sin(t)$ then $y''+y=0.$

Comment: @mfl, so whats a guideline for choosing trial function?

Comment: Maybe it helps to think of the product rule for differentiation.

Comment: The keyword is $\texttt{Modification Rule}$.

Comment: Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients

Answer (score 1):

We know that the general solution of the homogeneous equation

$$ y^{\prime\prime}+y=0 \tag{1}$$

can be found from solving the auxiliary algebraic

$$  m^2+1=0\text{, otaining }m=\pm i$$

giving the general solution

$$y=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin \tag{2}x$$

But we wish to solve the non-homogeneous equation

$$ y^{\prime\prime}+y=\cos x\tag{3} $$

Let

$$ u=y^{\prime\prime}+y \tag{4}$$

If we re-write equation $(3)$ using equation $(4)$ it becomes

$$u=\cos x$$

Because of equation $(2)$ we know that

$$u^{\prime\prime}+u=0\tag{5}$$

Using $(4)$ we can rewrite $(5)$ as

\begin{eqnarray}
(y^{\prime\prime}+y)^{\prime\prime}+(y^{\prime\prime}+y)&=&0\\
y^{(4)}+2y^{\prime\prime}+y&=&0\tag{6}
\end{eqnarray}

Equation $(6)$ is called the **annihilated** equation because the forcing function $\cos x$ in equation $(3)$ has been "annihilated" giving us a homogeneous equation with auxillary equation

$$ (m^2+1)^2=0\text{ with zeros }i,\,i,\,-i,\,-i$$

Because of the double zeros we must multiply by $x$ to get second solutions (this was learned from the study of **reduction of order**). So the general solution of the annihilated equation is

$$ y_a=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x+c_3x\cos x+c_4x\sin x \tag{7}$$

Now, using the **superposition principle** we compare equation $(7)$ to equation $(2)$ and find the general form of $y_p$ by removing from equation $(7)$ any similar terms in equation $(2)$. So we have

$$ y_p= Ax\cos x+Bx\sin x$$

From there you substitute $y_p$ into equation $(3)$ to discover the particular values of $A$ and $B$ which yield $\cos x$.

Note: Since this is a rather lengthy process, instructors sometime just advise that if the forcing function is a solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation, just multiply by $x$ (or $t$ as the case may be) to obtain the target $y_p$. But you wanted to know why, so I went into some detail to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

In this simple example you can just check that the given "Ansatz" works.

But we want a general theory for inhomogeneous linear ODEs of the form $$y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\ldots+a_1y'+a_0y=t^re^{\lambda t}\tag{1}$$
with $a_k\in{\mathbb C}$, $\ r\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$, and $\lambda\in{\mathbb C}$. The resulting recipe is an exercise in linear algebra, dealing with the operator $L:=p(D)$, where $D$ is ${d\over dt}$ and $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of the LHS of $(1)$.

Now, where does the factor $t$ in the solution functions come from? The ODE $y'=0$ has characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=\lambda$ with zero $\lambda_1=0$. On the other hand, the general solution of this ODE is $y(t)\equiv C=Ce^{\lambda_1 t}$.

The ODE $y''=0$ has characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2$ with double zero $\lambda_0=0$, and the general solution of this ODE is, as we all know, $y(t)=At+B=(At+B)e^{\lambda_0 t}$. This shows that already in the simplest example with a double root (and similarly in nonhomogeneous examples with RHS a solution of the associated homogeneous problem) we have solutions with a factor $t$. Furthermore the maximal exponent of $t$ will increase with the degeneracy of the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$.